# Can't install pango on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, pango

I'm trying to build gtk+1.3 on ubuntu and I'm getting an error during configure,

```
ld: cannot find -lpango
```

I tried installing a ton of pango libraries and its still not installed so I'm not sure what to do.  I keep testing it with

```
ld -lpango
```

But get the same error.  Has anyone successfully installed a pre-built pango on ubuntu?  From any repos?  Pango website says its difficult to build and I'd like to use a prebuilt binary if possible.

Also I had an error with atk not being found but all I had to do was install libatk1.0* and that was fixed.

Comment: Did you install `libpango1.0-dev`?

Comment: libpango1.0-dev is already the newest version
yep.  I think I did libpango1.0*, I did the graphite one, and I did another package that was supposed to contain pango, some grl one.

Answer (score 1):

`-lpango` is not the correct library name.

In fact, you should not be using `-l` options directly to link against Pango. Instead, you should be using `pkg-config`:

```
gcc -c -o program.o program.c `pkg-config --cflags pango`
gcc -o program program.o `pkg-config --libs pango`
```

Or

```
gcc -o program program.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs pango`
```

Since this is debugging a broken `configure` script, you can run `pkg-config` directly to see what it should be:

```
$ pkg-config --libs pango
-lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Frankly I'm surprised GTK+'s configure file doesn't also do this; you should file a bug report.

Comment: This helped me out so much